# Predictor-Corrector

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

Is Predictor Corrector Method able to solve ODE system??

Have a reference about it?

What i've seen on some sites is just about solving one single ODE.

If it's able, then please give an example, how to construct the predictor and the corrector.

(I mean apply the system to predictor and corrector method, not about to derive the formula)

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59310379/3088138 and decide if that already answers your question. That is only PECE (predict-evaluate-correct-evaluate), you can enhance it (very little) by repeating the CE part or looping it so that you get PE(CE)${}^n$. Or replace the CE part with a non-linear solver.

Comment: @LutzLehmann do you have a reference on when it is recommended to use a $PE(CE)^N$ method instead of a standard explicit method like a Dormand 7(8) or an RK8(9)? Thanks

Comment: @ChrisR : You use implicit methods for stiff systems, a first good reference is Hairer/Wanner: Solving ODE II: Stiff and DAE problems. There are several comparisons included of ODE where implicit methods work better. Also the implementation is discussed, PE(CE)$^n$ is only used for historical/didactic reasons, or perhaps for very large systems.